# Google Cloud Load Balancer + GKE ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've configured a Google Cloud Load Balancer as follows:

- GFE (frontend) listening on :443, https only
- Host matching + path matching on `/*`
- A single NEG (Network Endpoint Group) as a backend service for the load balancer

What I don't understand, is why an instance group is linked as a backend service to this Load Balancer (see below):
[image]

The instance group backend service links to the VM instances configured for my Kubernetes cluster. Also, if I remove the instance group backend service from this Load Balancer, `my-app` is still reachable over the global ip address.
However, after a few minutes, the instance group backend service is back and is linked to the Load Balancer again.

I can't seem to find anything about this behavior when using Network Endpoint Groups with a Google Cloud Load Balancer in the documentation or in any of the examples.

If you know why the instance group backend service is linked and why it returns after being removed, please reply.

Comment: Where and how do you remove your instance group backend?

Comment: In the Load Balancer details (via the Cloud Console), I edit and remove the instance group backend. So in the image above, the edit button.

Comment: Did you save the changes? (I already made this mistake....)

Comment: Yes, I did save. I also saw that the the instance group backend was removed from the Load Balancer. After a few minutes, I saw that it was added again.

Comment: Might this just be how Google has implemented NEGs when used with Kubernetes?

Comment: Ah, you create these backend through GKE and then you remove manually the automatically create resources, correct?

Comment: Indeed, that is correct.

Comment: Thus, yes, GKE try to maintain the state of the cluster as described in the YAML. Try to delete a VM, the effect will be the same. A new one will be created and the pod re deployed on it, automatically!

Comment: I do understand that it's caused by the fact that it's managed through my Kubernetes ingress, but I'm trying to understand *why* it is added in the first place. What's the role of having an instance group backend service linked to this load balancer when using NEGs? Is it required for the NEGs to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a GKE ingress there are a couple of options that can be defined on the yaml, one of these options is to have a [Default Backend defined](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#default_backend) where requests not matching any Host or path are sent to it.

By default when there is no Default Backend specified GKE automatically adds it’s own small web application to reply 404 to any unmatched requests, based on your screenshot the additional Instance group you see is this default backend not having been manually specified on creation.

Additionally deleting the Backend manually does not work since GKE always tries to keep all the resources in sync with what is described in the YAML, if you want to remove it instead you need to specify [your own default backend](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#default_backend) for unmatched requests.

Comment: That sounds completely logical! I missed that part in the docs, thanks for pointing it out. Let me see if the Google provided backend disappears when I specify a default backend.

Comment: Just verified, this is indeed the case. I specified the default backend and the instance group backend disappeared.